# Doctrine limit fileds in root entity when doing select with joins?

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm

Given `A` with one-to-many relationship with `B` I would like to ask for "a few columns from A and a few columns from B".

However I cant coax Doctrine into hydrationg `A` objects with just those columns and `B` object that will have only those columns.

Doctrine seam to understand only two polar options:

**ONE**

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('a')
 ->select('a', 'b')
 ->join('a.b', 'b')
```

Which will fetch all the data (which will cause serialization of that unneeded data).

**TWO**

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('b')
  ->select('a.id, a.fieldOne, a.fieldTwo, b.fieldThere')
  ->join('a.b', 'b')
```

In which case I will get array of `'id', 'fieldOne', 'fieldTwo', 'fieldThere'`. Which breaks convention with other repository methods which will return hydrated and nested objects.

**THERE** (thx @Artamiel)

I could use partial object like this:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('b')
  ->select('partial a.{id, fieldOne, fieldTwo}, partial b.{id, fieldThere}')
  ->join('a.b', 'b')
```

**Note:** partial require ids in field list, so added that to `b`

This however will not work as advertised as FOSRestBundle + JMS/Serializer **will** traverse fields not present, and more importantly relations not specified in select will load.

Comment: You can take a look at the chapter about [partial selects](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html).

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('b')
->select('PARTIAL a.{id, fieldOne, fieldTwo}, PARTIAL b.{fieldThere}')
->join('a.b', 'b')
```

*But be aware* that this will create your objects with all attributes - only difference is that you don't get the non-mentioned attributes hydrated into your result.

This means that noone exactly knows using your objects afterwards whether an attribute is really null or just null because you didn't hydrate it.

This syntax should be only used when you're sure what you're doing and is of high risk regarding pre-mature optimizations!

You could as well additionally

```
 $query->setHint(Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, 1);
```

to avoid attributes with 'null' which are not part of your partial object.

But again this means that you have the 'same' object with two different set of attributes which might lead into trouble, too.

See as well this entry: [How can I prevent loading of related entities in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15729224/how-can-i-prevent-loading-of-related-entities-in-symfony2)

Comment: (Sorry for fllipping accept button, I think I have bug somewhere in my serialization layer as end result do contain some additional values beyond fields in `partial` however if I `serialize` `getResult()` it do not show those values, so Your answer is correct)